# Can a basis always be chosen to diagonalise the matrix representation of an operator with the eigenvalues ordered arbitrarily?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, change-of-basis

In other words, if I can find a basis to diagonalise a matrix, $M$, such that its diagonal elements are its eigenvalues, $$M=\text{diag}(a,b,c,d),$$ can I always find a basis such that $$M=\text{diag}(c,b,a,d),$$ for example, or any other ordering of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, just change the order of  vectors in the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the matrix with respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is $\operatorname{diag}(a,b,c,d)$, then the matrix with respect to the basis $\{v_3,v_2,v_1,v_4\}$ is $\operatorname{diag}(c,b,a,d)$. That is, you apply to the vectors the same permutation that you applied to de eigenvalues.

Comment: Ah! Got it, thank you very much. Will accept this answer in 10 minutes because apparently I have to wait.